# Crear una consulta compuesta

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo una base de datos que tiene tabla departamento y tabla persona. departamento tiene nombre, dirección y numero y persona pues nombre, un identificador y numero de departamento donde trabaja.
tengo que crear la siguiente consulta Alta de Personas ( y Departamentos en caso de que no exista el departamento previamente)
entonces yo llego a hacer la primera parte, pero la parte de si no existe el departamento crearlo es la que no se meterla dentro

```
 public boolean altaPersona(Persona p) {
        String nombre = p.getNombre();
        int id = p.getIdentificador();
        int numDepartamento = p.getNumDepartamento();
        boolean flag = false;
        try {
            Statement orden = conn.createStatement();
            orden.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO persona(Nombre, id, numDepartamento)  VALUES('"
                    + nombre + "','" + id + "','" + numDepartamento + "')");
            orden.close();
            flag = true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return flag;
```

Comment: A que te referis con meterla adentro? en un solo query? el insert se hace a una sola tabla. Si vos queres que se haga todo en un solo paso, tenes que hacer un store procedure (que va a hacer 2 insert) o ejecutar los dos insert en una transaccion (donde seguro, primero tenes que ingresar el departamento)

Comment: Yo entiendo que si dice crea una persona y si el numero de departamento no existe la creas pues es que tiene que crear una persona comprobar si ese numero de departamento existe y si no pues hacer un insert de departamento todo  en el mismo metodo o eso entiendo yo

Comment: ok. pero no lo podes hacer en un solo sql. Las instrucciones sql son atomicas, no pueden ejecutar mil cosas a la vez. Si queres hacer eso, tenes que hacer el insert, despues un select que compruebe si existe el depto y despues otro insert si no existe. Aunque en general, uno hace al reves, primero crea el depto, porque probablemente la creacion de la persona no deberia hacerse a menos que exista el depto.

Comment: Yo me atengo a lo que dice el enunciado del ejercicio jaja. me puedes poner como seria que tenga una idea para hacer todo lo demas?

Comment: Es que tu ejercicio esta perfecto. Solo que no ejecutas una sola instruccion sql. Haces 3... no hay forma de hacerlo en una. No existe.

Comment: con subconsultas? o una mezcla en plan haces un select para el departamento si no te da nada haces un insert de departamento y luego de persona.
si te da resultado es que el departamento existe y solo haces un insert de persona

Comment: Exacto!!! eso ulitmo es lo que tenes que hacer.. sin subconsultas... ;) tenes la logica correcta...

Comment: La logica sera buena pero no se ponerlo nose como hacerlo es el probelma

Comment: Si esto es parte de un ejercicio de aprendizaje, no te meteré prisa (seguramente lo verás más adelante), pero si esto es una aplicación "real", te aconsejo urgentemente que uses *preparedStatements*, donde puedes parametrizar los valores a insertar para evitar inyección de SQL

Comment: ya aclaro que era un ejercicio @PabloLozano, por eso ni me meti con eso...

Comment: preparedStatements, eso me ha sonado a chino como poco jaja. Podria alguno hacerme como seria correctamente el codigo para tenerlo de base y aprender. soy mas de aprender viendo algo hecho que leyendo teoria

Comment: @carlosdiaz pasate por el [chat] y podemos ayudarte a que empujes la logica. Tu app esta perfecta hasta ahora, solo te faltan mas instrucciones...