# ¿Cómo realizar una consulta dependiendo del resultado de otra?

Tags: java, sql

Realizar un consulta con un condicional si da resultado esa consulta hace una cosa si no hace otra.

Me explico estoy haciendo un ejercicio que nos ha mandado el profesor.

Tengo que crear una persona en una base de datos en java y esta persona tiene un número de departamento.

- Si el número de departamento existe creo a la persona.
- Si el número no existe creo el departamento y creo a la persona.

Un ejemplo `select nombre from departamento where departamento = 2` si eso da un resultado por ejemplo compras entonces `insert into persona (..........)` si no da resultado `insert into departamento (.....)` y tb `insert into persona (....)` mi problema es ese si da resultado y si no como lo pongo.

Yo como hacer para crear una persona y un departamento pero no como mezclar las 2 y tener el condicional.

```
public class ConectorBD {

private String bd = "test";
private String login = "empleado";
private String password = "empleado";
private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/" + bd;
private Connection conn = null;

public ConectorBD() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
        if (conn != null) {
            System.out.println("Conección a base de datos " + bd + ". lista");
        }
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
 public Connection getConnection() {
    return conn;
}

public void desconectar() {
    conn = null;
    System.out.println("La conexion a la  base de datos " + bd + " ha terminado");
}
public boolean altaPersona(Persona p) {
    String nombre = p.getNombre();
    int id = p.getIdentificador();
    int numDepartamento = p.getNumDepartamento();
    boolean flag = false;
    try {
        Statement orden = conn.createStatement();
        orden.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO persona(Nombre, id, numDepartamento)  VALUES('"
                + nombre + "','" + id + "','" + numDepartamento + "')");
        orden.close();
        flag = true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return flag;
}
public boolean altaDepartamento(Departamento d) {
    String nombre = d.getNombre();
    String direccion = d.getDireccion();
    int numDepartamento = d.getNumDepartamento();
    boolean flag = false;
    try {
        Statement orden = conn.createStatement();
        orden.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO persona(Nombre, direccion, numDepartamento)  VALUES('"
                + nombre + "','" + direccion + "','" + numDepartamento + "')");
        orden.close();
        flag = true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: Tienes que hacer un SELECT a la BBDD para cosultar si el numero de departamento existe, y en función de lo que te devuelva lo introduces en un if.

Comment: Basicamente, van al mismo curso y tienen el mismo profesor, y se enfrentan al mismo problema: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/261486/324

Comment: jajaj pues si ese es compañero mio. @David_helo ya se la idea mi problema es el codgio la logica la tengo muy clara . pongamos un ejemplo
un select nombre from departamento where departamento = 2  si eso da un resultado por ejemplo compras entonces insert into persona (..........) si no da resultado insert into departamento (.....) y tb insert into persona (....)
mi problema es ese si da resultado y si no

Comment: Y si son compañeros y tienen el mismo problema, porque no analizan el problema juntos? asi como esta, esta pregunta es un duplicado de aquella... :/

Comment: Por la sencilla razon de que ninguno de los sabemos y yo no sabia que el estaba aqui ni que habia escrito. ademas mi pregunta esta mas clara explicada :P

Answer (score 0):

Primero cambiaría este método porque en realidad no estas desconectando:

```
public void desconectar() throws SQLException {
    if (conn != null) {
       conn.close();
       conn = null;
       System.out.println("La conexion a la  base de datos " + bd + " ha terminado");
   }
}
```

Luego haría un método para saber si el departamento existe:

```
public boolean existeDepartamento(int numeroDeDepartamento) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT NOMBRE FROM DEPARTAMENTOS WHERE NUMERO="+numeroDeDepartamento;
    java.sql.ResultSet resultado = conn.executeQuery(sql);
    return (resultado.next()); //método next() retorna verdadero si encontró por
                               //lo menos un registro, o en este caso el departamento
                               //con ese número
}
```

Si te piden que si no existe el departamento lo des de alta, entonces estoy suponiendo que tienes los datos del departamento. Haría un método así:

```
public void altaDePersonaYDepartamentoSiNoExiste(Persona p, Departamento d) throws SQLException {
    if (!existeDepartamento(d.numeroDeDepartamento())) {
        altaDepartamento(d);
    }
    altaPersona(p);
}
```

Comment: pero tiene que ser todo dentro del mismo metodo no en varios

Comment: Pues mete el código dentro del otro metodo, y evalua el if con (!resultado.next())